# Use central limit to solve a problem

Tags: probability, probability-theory, central-limit-theorem

I am asked to solve the following question using central limit theorem.
In an election between two candidates, A and B, one million individuals cast theirvote. Among these, 2000 know candidate A from her election campaign and vote unanimously for her.The remaining 998000 voters are undecided and make their decision independently of each other byflipping a fair coin.Approximate the probability pA that candidate A wins up to 3 significant figures. 
 It's easy to solve directly.
PA = $\frac{0.5(10000-2000)+2000}{10000}$ = 0.501. However, I am quite confused about how to solve this problem by central limit theorem.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: That is not the probability that the candidate wins. That is the expected amount of the votes that they get. You will need to use the standard deviation and the mean (expected value) to get the answer.

Comment: So in this case 0.501 is the mean, not the probability?

Answer (score 1):

Let $X=$ *number of voters for candidate A* among the remaining $998,000$ individuals.  Then $X$ is binomial with $n=998000$ and $p=1/2$, therefore approximately normal with $\mu=np=499000$ and $\sigma^2np(1-p)=249500$.  Now calculate $P(X>498000)$, which is surprisingly high.

Comment: Where did you apply CLT in this case? I am quite confused about how CLT words in this situation.

Comment: Consider a binomial distribution as sum of identical and independent Bernoulli random variables.  As such a binomial distribution my be approximated by a normal one, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Normal_approximation